# NVDA screen reader using ARIA for Checkbox state

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I am using `<ng-select>` with `<ng-option>`. I want to use NVDA to say the state of the checkbox, expanded or collapsed how I want. It could be any text. Reading through the documentation I can see the label, labelldby but I don't see a way to use them.
The accessibility changes are only for the screen reader, and the code is as follows without aria.

```
<ng-select class="u-focus"
      name="frequency"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedFrequencyId"
      (change)="changeFrequencyUnit(subscription, $event)"
      [disabled]="true"
      [searchable]="false">
        <ng-option *ngFor="let frequency of frequencyUnits" [value]="frequency.id">
        </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Your code creates a select with options. The selected state would be determined by ng-selected directive and ultimately by the selected attribute. Perhaps something is styled to resemble a checkbox?

Comment: Yes, the `<ng-select>` resembles a checkbox with the options looking like a listbox. The `aria-label` with custom text is spoken for collapsed `<ng-select> or combobox` in StackBlitz but does not speak the label for VS Code deployments on the local machine.